# Only-child pseudo-class for first-line pseudo-element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

Is there a way to avoid the "red highlight" in the last example?

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4s42cnrL/)

```
<h3>should be:</h3>

    <div class="demo">
    <p>foo foo</p>
    <p>bar bar</p>
    </div>

<hr>

    <div class="demo">
    <p>foo foo<br>foo foo</p>
    <p>bar bar</p>
    </div>

<hr>

    <div class="demo">
    <p>foo foo<br>foo foo</p>
    </div>

<h3>should not be:</h3>

    <div class="demo">
    <p>foo foo</p>
    </div>
```

This is what I currently use:

```
.demo p:first-child::first-line {
    color: red;
}
```

But, it highlights all examples, including the last one. I also tried these two:

```
.demo p:first-child::first-line:not(:only-child) {
    color: red;
}

/* and... */

.demo p:first-child::first-line:not(:only-of-type) {
    color: red;
}
```

But it seems it just brokes all the highlight in all demos.

Is there way to achieve the desired result? (Remove "red highlight" from the last example).

(JS/jQuery solution is also ok, but, if it could be solved with CSS, it would be much better).

Screenshot with desired result:

[image]

Comment: It already works fine in Chrome at least. Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: @powerbuoy What exactly code and result do you mean? I also use Chrome. I need to get the result as shown in the screenshot. None of the CSS examples in my post doesn't do it for me. (Sorry if my English isn't perfect).

Comment: I think CSS isn't enough because there is no way to distinct `p` with `br` and  `p` without `br` tags. In your second solution with `only-child` - you should use it that way: `.demo p:first-child:not(:only-child):first-line` (only-child immidiately after first child, not after first-line).

Comment: you can also filter it as not the last-child https://jsfiddle.net/4s42cnrL/5/

Comment: Is the criteria _only first line when there is multiple lines_?

Comment: @GCyrillus Yes, but it brokes the 3rd example

Comment: @johnc.j. oh yes, mix blend mode could fake it somehow : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PmaZYj  just for info, do not use for real .  red being close to black, blending makes it not so obvious

Comment: I must've suffered from sleep deprivation - it does _not_ work in chrome, no :P Targeting an element based on its contents (basically a parent selector) is so far not possible in CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution in jQuery.

CSS:

```
.demo p:first-child:first-line {
  color: red;
}
.demo .not-red:first-line {
 color: green !important;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.demo p:only-child:not(:has(br))').each(function() {
  $(this).addClass('not-red');
});
```

JS will add `not-red` class only to paragraphs that doesn't contain `br` tags and paragraphs that are only child.

### [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/makshh/pen/MmXaqB)

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks. I should look comments below my question before accepting your answer. (Also there is a small typo in Codepen).

Comment: Do you really need that !important? Is there no other approach to this problem without having that there (hint hint)? Or should this be left as an exercise to the reader?

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to set the color on `:first-child` and then override with `:only-child`:

```
.demo p:first-child::first-line {
    color: red;
}

.demo p:only-child, .demo p:only-child::first-line {
  color: inherit;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/4s42cnrL/4/

Comment: I should test it more, but at first glance, the 3rd example stopped worked.

Comment: I removed the `::first-line` for simplicity. Added back to answer after edit.

Comment: Hm... Currently, the code here and at jsFiddle is slightly different, as I could see. The code from here is still brokes in the 3rd example. And code in jsFiddle highlights all examples (including the last). Tested in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

please use

```
.demo:not(:last-of-type) p:first-child::first-line {
    color: red;
}
```

https://jsbin.com/doqenagapa/4/edit?html,css,output

Comment: No, you just "cheated" :)

Comment: I mean, the highlight should be removed accordingly to inner structure of div. In your example, you filtered out the div itself, based on it's position...